# onActivated wont trigger in Quasar (vue3) component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework

For some reason the onActivated function in vue3 wont trigger and cannot figure out why. It is not the first time I am implementing this but for some reason nothing happens. I am using vue 3.0.0. Here is my code and component

**Index.vue**

```
<template>
  <MyComp />
</template>

<script setup>
import MyComp from "../components/MyComp.vue";
</script>
```

**MyComp.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>{{ el }}</div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted, onActivated } from "vue";

const el = ref("Hello");

onMounted(() => {
  console.log("onMounted");
});
onActivated(() => {
  console.log("onActivated");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onActivated` only triggers for components inside a `KeepAlive` tag, but you don't have any `KeepAlive` tags in the code you posted, so `onMounted` should be all you need. See https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onactivated